# Pandas: create new dataframe from data extracted from string in old dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a dataframe with sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY': ['1','2','3'], 'RECORD': ['1','1','1'], 'SERIAL': ['1470','2321','300'], 'REMARKS': ['FRUIT[APPLES,ORANGES,PEARS] IS HEALTHY FOR YOU','I LIKE FRUIT[BANANAS,CHERRIES,GRAPES], BUT I DON\'T LIKE FRUIT[CANTALOPE,HONEYDEW]', 'THERE IS FRUIT[LEMONS,ORANGES,GRAPEFRUIT] @ 1234']})
```

[image: First Dataframe]

I need to extract out the fruit into a new dataframe associated with the KEY, RECORD, and SERIAL. It should look like this when finished:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY': ['1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3'], 'RECORD': ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'], 'SERIAL': ['1470','1470','1470','2321','2321','2321','2321','2321','300','300','300'], 'FRUIT': ['APPLES','ORANGES','PEARS','BANANAS','CHERRIES','GRAPES','CANTALOPE','HONEYDEW','LEMONS','ORANGES','GRAPEFRUIT'], 'CODE': ['null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','1234','1234','1234']})
```

[image: Second Dataframe]

From the research I've done, it looks like I could use the str.split and/or str.extract, but I'm not sure how to match up each fruit with the KEY, RECORD, and SERIAL. On top of that, the last record has "@ 1234". That information needs to also be extracted and matched up with the 3 fruits listed before it.

I'm guessing the first step in this process is to extract out the fruit, which should be easy because they are all in a series in the string.

Any recommendations on how to tackle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['FruitList'] = df['REMARKS'].str.extract('\[(.+?)\]').squeeze().str.split(',')
df['CODE'] = df['REMARKS'].str.extract('@\s(\d+)')
df.explode('FruitList')
```

Output:

```
  KEY RECORD SERIAL                                            REMARKS   FruitList  CODE
0   1      1   1470     FRUIT[APPLES,ORANGES,PEARS] IS HEALTHY FOR YOU      APPLES   NaN
0   1      1   1470     FRUIT[APPLES,ORANGES,PEARS] IS HEALTHY FOR YOU     ORANGES   NaN
0   1      1   1470     FRUIT[APPLES,ORANGES,PEARS] IS HEALTHY FOR YOU       PEARS   NaN
1   2      1   2321  I LIKE FRUIT[BANANAS,CHERRIES,GRAPES], BUT I D...     BANANAS   NaN
1   2      1   2321  I LIKE FRUIT[BANANAS,CHERRIES,GRAPES], BUT I D...    CHERRIES   NaN
1   2      1   2321  I LIKE FRUIT[BANANAS,CHERRIES,GRAPES], BUT I D...      GRAPES   NaN
2   3      1    300   THERE IS FRUIT[LEMONS,ORANGES,GRAPEFRUIT] @ 1234      LEMONS  1234
2   3      1    300   THERE IS FRUIT[LEMONS,ORANGES,GRAPEFRUIT] @ 1234     ORANGES  1234
2   3      1    300   THERE IS FRUIT[LEMONS,ORANGES,GRAPEFRUIT] @ 1234  GRAPEFRUIT  1234
```

And you can drop REMARKS if you would like:

```
df.explode('FruitList').drop('REMARKS', axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  KEY RECORD SERIAL   FruitList  CODE
0   1      1   1470      APPLES   NaN
0   1      1   1470     ORANGES   NaN
0   1      1   1470       PEARS   NaN
1   2      1   2321     BANANAS   NaN
1   2      1   2321    CHERRIES   NaN
1   2      1   2321      GRAPES   NaN
2   3      1    300      LEMONS  1234
2   3      1    300     ORANGES  1234
2   3      1    300  GRAPEFRUIT  1234
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It gave me a starting point. My only issue is that the brackets are coming across to the new column, which is keeping the exploding from working. However, at least I now know about squeezing/exploding.

Comment: From my testing, the split and squeezing are working fine. It is the exploding that is not working. All it returns is the fruit list split apart like this: [APPLES, ORANGES, PEARS] still all on the same line.

Comment: I got it finally. I had to reference the explode statement back to df then it worked (df = df.explode('FruitList'))